# Touchpad utilizes CPU even if totally disabled in BIOS and X

Tags: kernel, touchpad, thinkpad, synaptics, interrupts

I have problems with CPU spikes from irq/204-rmi4_sm when I touch the touchpad in a Lenovo Thinkpad Extreme. I have disabled the Touchpad in BIOS as well as in X. However still the IRQ is fired every time the pad is touched or palm rests on it. It is disabled though.

Linux seal 5.15.0-23-lowlatency #23-Ubuntu, 22.04

Is it possible to disable a specific interrupt handling?

Comment: Hello. You are asking about a version of Ubuntu that has yet to be released. It does not exist yet. It is off topic on this site. Sorry.

Comment: I am sorry little earthling I came from the future back here. My fault. I will step into my time machine 3 weeks forth.